# Sending tinder messages off the command line

Tags: facebook, bash, http, curl, mitmproxy

I am trying to use [this](https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467) api documentation to send Tinder messages (etc) via the Linux command line. Unfortunately, I can't even get past the authentication step. I follow the directions as best I can (getting my facebook id off of [this site](http://findmyfacebookid.com/)). I end up with a command similar to the following:

```
> curl -X POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth --data '{"facebook_token":"LETTERSandSTUFF", "facebook_id":"allnumbers"}'
```

I've tried a couple variations of this as well, but no matter what, I get back the same result:

```
{"code":401,"error":"FacebookTokenRequired"}
```

I also tried to use mitmproxy to learn more about what Tinder and other programs were actually doing. However, even though mitmproxy was recording my computer accurately, when I tried to proxy my phone through mitmproxy's port, it ceased to load anything (it would time out).

Mostly I would just like to be able to send messages on Tinder somehow, but if anybody has any idea why mitmproxy isn't working, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I figured out that I wasn't including the necessary headers. I guess I didn't read the api thoroughly enough, because I thought all of the headers would be optional. However, I still don't know what the X-Auth-Token header is supposed to be....

Comment: So I think I might have been getting blocked by the tinder api for too many posts or something. Anyway, I changed my IP and it worked. I now see that the X-Auth-Token is the result of the first request, and doesn't need to be included in the auth setp.